# Get max subsum from an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, sum

I had this question on a test recently and don't understand at all what the question is asking for, especially based on the examples:

> **max_subsum**
>
> Write a method, max_subsum(numbers), which takes an array and returns
>   the start and end    indices of the consecutive range which has the
>   largest sum.
>
> max_subsum([100, -101, 200, -3, 1000]) == [2, 4]
>
> max_subsum([1, 2, 3]) == [0, 2]
>
> Hints: iterate through all the subarrays; compute the sum of each
>   subarray and compare to the max subsum seen so far. A subarray is
>   defined by its start index and end indices, so iterate through all
>   pairs of indices. You should probably use two loops, one nested inside
>   the other.

I don't see any subarrays in the examples. The output from the examples simply shows the indices of smallest and largest values in the array. If that's what the question is asking for, then what summation of subarrays is happening. I must be missing something simple, I just don't know what that is. Does someone else see it?

Comment: By "subarray" the question means a part of an array. So if the array is [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13] then [2, 3, 5] is a subarray of that array.

Comment: The subarray in the first example is `[200, -3, 1000]` based on the indices `[2, 4]`. That has a sumsum of 1197=200-3+1000. That is the largest subsum of consecutive members from the original array.

Comment: The output is the index for the sub-array that start in A and end in B([A, B]) respectively. In the above example : [2,4] = 200 + (-3) + 1000 = 1197 is the maximum consecutive sum

Comment: The answer is in the comments above. (@RussellZahniser please enhance your note and post it as an answer.) But IMO the question is phrased very poorly. Even *"consecutive range"* is very ambiguous.

Comment: Wow. I didn't read it that way. When I read "subarrays", I thought of an array of arrays. That's what threw me off. I thought the question was asking for the array within the array that had the largest sum. So, the question is actually asking to find the set of consecutive elements in the array that have the largest sum, and output the starting and end indices of that set? I get it. I agree @Borodin. At the very least providing a better example would have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the first array's subarrays along with their sums:

```
[100].inject(:+)                       #=>   100
[100, -101].inject(:+)                 #=>    -1
[100, -101, 200].inject(:+)            #=>   199
[100, -101, 200, -3].inject(:+)        #=>   196
[100, -101, 200, -3, 1000].inject(:+)  #=>  1196
     [-101].inject(:+)                 #=>  -101
     [-101, 200].inject(:+)            #=>    99
     [-101, 200, -3].inject(:+)        #=>    96
     [-101, 200, -3, 1000].inject(:+)  #=>  1096
           [200, -3, 1000].inject(:+)  #=>  1197
                [-3, 1000].inject(:+)  #=>   997
                    [1000].inject(:+)  #=>  1000
```

`[200, -3, 1000]` has the largest sum

Comment: This is certainly what the question intended, but there is no acknowledged thing called a *"subarray"*, and you are repeating the mistake in the original question.

Comment: @Borodin it's called "subarray" in the [`Array#slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-slice) docs: *"returns a subarray specified by range of indices"*

Comment: The meaning of a "subarray" is resolved in the comments to the question, n'est-ce pas?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my quick solution to your problem =)

Split the calls in order to understand what I'm doing =)

```
def max_subsum(a)
    (0...a.length).flat_map { |i| (i...a.length).map { |j| i..j } }.inject([a[0], 0..0]) { |max, i| a[i].inject(:+) > max.first ? [a[i].inject(:+),i ]: max }.last
end
```

Output:

```
max_subsum([100, -101, 200, -3, 1000])
=> 2..4
max_subsum([1, 2, 3])
=> 0..2
```

You can convert to array.. I did not bother as I like the range =)

A dynamic programming solution to this problem would be more efficient but I think you are expected to provide something along the lines of what I did during an exam :-)

**Explanation:**

```
(0...a.length).flat_map { |i| (i...a.length).map { |j| i..j } }
```

returns to me all the possible consecutive positions in the array. You can consider this your nested loops.

I'm then injecting the value `[a[0], 0..0]` and assuming it's the solution: `a[0]` being the max value and `0..0` being the start to end index. Inside inject, I'm comparing the max to the sum of the current slice of the array from flat_map, if it's bigger, I return the slice and the max.

Answer (score 0):

The [Kadane's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) is what you want. [In this blog you could find good references too.](http://www.rerun.me/blog/2012/08/30/maximum-continuous-subarray-problem-kandanes-algorithm/)

Comment: This answer is missing a *lot*. The OP's problem was in understanding the question, not in writing a solution. What interpretation of the question do your links help with, and how do they help?

Comment: The question was answered in the comments , this is a explanation of the algorithm for his knowledge.

Comment: That's exactly it. Thanks @Vkt0r

Comment: The first paragraph of the Wiki reference provides a clear, concise answer to the question.

Answer (score -2):

```
static int[] maxSubSum(int[] arr) {
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    int thisSum = arr[0];
    int maxSum = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (thisSum > 0) {
            thisSum += arr[i];
            if (thisSum > maxSum) {
                maxSum = thisSum;
                end = i;
            }
        } else {
            thisSum = arr[i];
            if (thisSum > maxSum) {
                maxSum = thisSum;
                start = i;
                end = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return new int[]{start, end};
}
```

}

Comment: https://note.youdao.com/ynoteshare1/index.html?id=5ba0e15270a54c194ccaacc5a4569b70&type=note