# Ruby - find subarray indices

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm having problem finding a way to extract the indices of a subarray.

**The problem**: find the subarray with the max value from one original array.

**My solution**: Finds the right array, but returns the values in the array.

**I need**: the start index and end index of the max subarray; example: `[2, 4]`.

**My code:**

```
def max_subarr(arr)
  (0...arr.length).inject([arr.first]) do |max_sub, i|
    (i...arr.length).each do |x|
      if max_sub.inject(:+) < arr[i..x].inject(:+)
        max_sub = arr[i..x]
      end
    end
    max_sub
  end
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated - and please include a short explanation of what I'm doing wrong.  I know that max_sub returns the values of `arr[i..x]`, but I cannot for the life of me just return the index values of `max_sub[i]` and `max_sub[x]`.

Comment: You are using your own terms like "subarray" without explanation. You should give and example input and expected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561593/get-max-subsum-from-an-array/21565638

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do this:

```
indexes_arr = [2, 4]
range = Range.new(*indexes_arr)
arr[range]
```

**EDITED:**

In order to get the indices in your code, you need to save them each time you find a bigger subarray.

This is your edited code:

```
def max_subarr(arr)
 start_index, end_index = 0, 0
 (0...arr.length).inject([arr.first]) do |max_sub, i|
  (i...arr.length).each do |x|
    if max_sub.inject(:+) < arr[i..x].inject(:+)
     max_sub = arr[i..x]
     start_index, end_index = i, x
    end
   end
   max_sub
 end
 return [start_index, end_index]
end



max_subarr([98, -99, 198, -2, 950])
=> [2,4]
```

Comment: I am not getting the question. Would you help me ?

Comment: This is a duplicate for a question we answered a week ago. Say you have %w[a a a b b 3 3 3 3 0 b b c] ... he wants to find %w[3 3 3 3]. He says he's able to find the indices but unable to get the array. My answer tells him how to convert what he's found into the array he's looking for :-)

Comment: Does he want maximum occurrence contiguous sub array?

Comment: I think he wants this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561593/get-max-subsum-from-an-array/21565638#21565638

Comment: I think he might want the sum but I am not sure.. Since he says he knows how to find it, I only told him how to convert to an array :-)

Comment: Ok. I was also confused.

Comment: Sorry if I was a bit confusing, but you have it backwards.  If you run my code you can see that I am able to get the ARRAY, but NOT the INDICES.  For example, if you have array [98, -99, 198, -2, 950], then my code will return [198, -2, 950], which is the subarray that creates the maximum value possible if you were to find the sum of every subarray possible.  What I need my code to do is give me [2, 4], which would be the start and end indices of the max subarray.

Comment: As for what I mean by subarray, it's just any possible connected array within one original array (i.e. [array[0]..array[3]], or [array[2]..array[6]], so long as they are in order and connected, meaning you could not have [array[0], array[2], array[4]], as you would be missing indexes 1 and 3.) I did follow your link Abdo, which is exactly what I'm looking for in theory, but I would like to be able to use my own code and understand what I am missing since I am very close to a solution.

Comment: You were very close... You only need to remember the indices, that's all =)

Comment: Thanks a lot Abdo.  You just put a troubled mind at ease.  This would have bothered me all night.  I can't believe that's all I needed.  Lesson learned!

Comment: Haha :-) No prob... Have a great night :-)